How to enable DML statements on BigTable via BigQuery?
I have a BigTable and I am querying it from BigQuery. For an urgent production issue, we need to delete some records based on a condition.
However when I type DELETE query, I get error saying:

DML statements are only supported over tables that have data stored in BigQuery. Unsupported table: table_name

Is there a way to delete these records from GCP console?

I used gcloud cbt tool to delete corresponding rows.

BigQuery query federation is in Read Only mode. You can only read the data, never change them.
However, you have a brand new feature in BigTable named BigTable studio accessible here: https://console.cloud.google.com/bigtable/instances/phenix-instance-prod/studio/query
(select your project if not selected by default)
It's a preview version and you can run SQL query over BigTable and, maybe, run DML (because it's totally new and in preview, it might have some limitation, like DML commands)

Thanks for the response. I gave it a try, but all queries are timing out in BigTable studio.
